# Entity Embedding concatenate with 1d cnn keras R

Tags: r, python-3.x, keras

I'm trying to fit a multi input model with keras. The data consists of numerical and categorical, so I defined two branch of input, categorical with entity embedding, and the numerical with 1D CNN, Here is my data:

```
dim(Y_train)       = c(1000,1)
dim(X_categorical) = c(1000,20)
dim(X_numerical)   = c(1000, 21, 50)
```

and here is my model:

```
library(data.table)
library(keras)
unique_cat_num <- vector()
for(cat in ctgrc_cols){
  unique_cat_num = append(unique_cat_num,length(unique(myDT[,get(cat)])))
}
embed_input <- list()
  for(cat in ctgrc_vars){
    embed_input = append(embed_input,layer_input(shape = 1, name = paste0("input_",cat)))
  }

  embed_dim_vec <- vector()
  for(i in 1:length(ctgrc_vars)){
    embed_dim_vec = append(embed_dim_vec,min((unique_cat_len[i] + 1) %/% 2, 50))
  }

  embed_out <- list()
  for(i in 1:length(ctgrc_vars)){
    layout    = layer_embedding(object = embed_input[[i]], input_dim = unique_cat_len[i] + 1, output_dim = embed_dim_vec[i], name = paste0("embedding_",ctgrc_vars[i]))
    layout    = layer_flatten(layout)
    embed_out = append(embed_out, layout)
  }
Conv_input  <- layer_input(shape = c(21, 50))

conv_flat <- Conv_input %>%
      layer_conv_1d(filters = 64, kernel_size = 3, activation = "relu") %>% 
      layer_conv_1d(filters = 64, kernel_size = 3, activation = "relu") %>% 
      layer_max_pooling_1d() %>% 
      layer_conv_1d(filters = 32, kernel_size = 3, activation = "relu") %>% 
      layer_conv_1d(filters = 32, kernel_size = 3, activation = "relu") %>% 
      layer_global_max_pooling_1d()%>%
      layer_dropout(0.3) %>% 
      layer_dense(units = 32, activation = "relu") %>% 
      layer_flatten() 

output <- layer_concatenate(list(embed_out, conv_flat)) %>% 
    layer_dense(units = 32, activation = "relu") %>% 
    layer_dropout(0.3) %>%
    layer_dense(units = out_neuron, activation = "sigmoid")

model <- keras_model(inputs = list(embed_input, Conv_input), outputs = output)
```

When I try to try the model I'm getting this value error:

```
ValueError: A `Concatenate` layer requires inputs with matching shapes except for the concat axis. Got inputs shapes: [[(None, 14), (None, 2), (None, 6), (None, 3), (None, 2), (None, 2), (None, 17), (None, 4), (None, 5), (None, 5), (None, 5), (None, 5), (None, 5), (None, 5), (None, 5), (None, 5), 
                                                                                                                          Called from: py_call_impl(callable, dots$args, dots$keywords)
```

Any Advice?

Answer (score 0):

The Problem result of embedded list!
 the Entity embedding -> embed_input is a list, so with list(embed_input,Conv_input) the results is an embeded list which not keras wanted a flat list.
and the embed_out is the same.